# Animated Cursor not Moving on screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have A problem Where I cant Get My Cursor To move I am using html5 css3 and java script i can get the coordinates in the console but the cursor will not move on the screen.

Comment: add the code to your request to permit us to reproduce please

Answer (score 0):

Cursor is an device input you can't take the control of the mouse of your user ... I think and it's better like that to avoid some bad usage